# In the offer method, what does "return stk1.push(element).equals(element)" do?

Tags: java, binary, stack, queue, push

I am trying to understand the difference between the first offer() method and the second offer() method given below. When programming in NetBeans in Java, the hint was given that the if statement in the first offer method is redundant. After configuring the if statement, the code inside the offer method now reads "return stk1.push(element).equals(element);". What does the line of code, "return stk1.push(element).equals(element)" do exactly; how did it handle the redundancy?

```
//FIRST - my attempt 
public BinaryPollQueue()
{
    stk1 = new Stack<>();
    stk2 = new Stack<>();
} //BinaryPollQueue

public boolean offer(E element)
{
    if(stk1.push(element).equals(element))
    {
        return true;
    } //if
    else
    {
        return false;
    } //else

} //offer

//SECOND - configured based on hint given 
public BinaryPollQueue()
{
    stk1 = new Stack<>();
    stk2 = new Stack<>();
} //BinaryPollQueue

public boolean offer(E element)
{
    return stk1.push(element).equals(element);
} //offer
```

Answer (score 0):

`stk1.push(element).equals(element)` returns a `boolean` value. That's the reason it can appear in the condition of an `if` statement in the first place.

Since your `if` statement returns `true` when `stk1.push(element).equals(element)` is `true` and returns `false` otherwise, you can simply return the `boolean` value `stk1.push(element).equals(element)` and get rid of the `if` statement.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!!